# Curl and javascript submit

Tags: php, javascript, forms, curl, submit

I try to curl a page with a javascript submit process with out any luck... So I ask the community for some help!

Here is the form :

```
<script> 
    <!--
    function vallogin(){
        document.formlogin.action = "./index.php?vallogin=1";
        document.formlogin.submit();
    }
    -->
</script> 


<form name="formlogin" method="post"> 
<div class="headerblocgris"> 
<span class="txtnoir12">| Accès |</span> 
</div> 
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">                       
<tr>
<td class="txtnoir12">Login</td> 
<td><input name="txtlogin" type="text" size="15" /></td> 
<td><span class="txtnoir12">Password</span></td> 
<td> 
<input name="txtmdp" type="password" size="15" /> 
<input type="image" name="vallogin" src="images/bt_go.gif" align="absmiddle" /> 
</td> 
</tr>  
</table> 
</form>
```

And my curl function :

```
{
         /**
         * Connexion
         */
        $URL = 'http://www.affiliatevista.com/index.php?vallogin=1';

        $data = array(
                    'txtlogin' => $this->login,
                    'txtmdp' => $this->passe,
                    'formlogin' => '',
                    'vallogin' => '',

                );
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->implode_array($data));
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_getCookie());
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->_getCookie());
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $String = curl_exec($this->ch);
        echo $String;
    }
```

Thanks for your input, the code above doesn't validate the form, I think I miss something with the submit validation process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call the vallogin() function?

I don't see a submit button in your code, so something like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="vallogin(); return false" />
```

might work.

Using JQuery and AJAX to do a post then return a result might be a better option though.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Or it could be you need an onsubmit="vallogin()" in your form attributes.

Comment: The form is not mine but on a site I want to use the curl function http://www.affiliatevista.com/ as you can see they don't add the onclick inside the input so I must deal with it and call the vallogin inside curl isn't it?

Comment: @henri You've lost me a bit there. You can't execute javascript in php. One is client side the other server side. Do you mean you've no access to the javascript and html, so you are trying to call the submit function from the server?

Comment: So if I understand I can't use CURL with form validate by javascrip, even if I find the destination of the form validation : /index.php?vallogin=1 ? Thanks logic-unit!

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is post the form @logic-unit has the proper way of executing the page

on your php code you seem to be doing things ok, just make sure you identify when to call the 
function

```
if( isset($_GET['vallogin']) && $_GET['vallogin'] === 1 ){
//execute function here
}
```

just make sure you dont confuse your GET and your POST, you seem to be passing user, password data, which should be on the _POST object of php, or you might even consider using _REQUEST